# How to understand this equation $L(L^2(a,b), \mathbb{R}) = L^2(a,b)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

In our lecture there is the following sentence:

"The function $J:H^1_{a}(a,b) \times L^\infty(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is assumed to be Fréchet differentiable. We assume the partial derivatives can be extended to linear and continous functionals on $L^2(a,b)$ for which we will be using the same symbol. For example $\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}(\bar{y}, \bar{u}) \in L(L^2(a,b), \mathbb{R}) = L^2(a,b)$."

I do not understand the last two sentences. For me the Fréchet derivative  $\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}(\bar{y}, \bar{u})$ is a linear and continous function from $L^\infty(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ hence
$\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}(\bar{y}, \bar{u}) \in L(L^\infty(a,b), \mathbb{R})$. I understand that this function can be interpreted as a function in $L(L^2(a,b), \mathbb{R})$ by the assumption. But how could you describe (and treat) this as an element in $L^2(a,b)$?

Comment: is this riesz representation theorem?

Comment: If $L(L^2(a,b),\mathbb R)$ is the topological dual space of $L^2(a,b)$ (that is, the space of continuous linear maps $L^2(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb R$), then the equation $L(L^2(a,b),\mathbb R)=L^2(a,b)$ is the Riesz representation theorem, that is: For every continuous linear map $F:L^2(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ corresponds to a unique $g\in L^2(a,b)$ such that $F(\phi)=\langle \phi,g\rangle$ (where $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the usual scalar product on $L^2(a,b)$)